# ¿Cuál es el orden correcto para llamar los eventos del fixture en Angular (Unit Testing)?

Tags: angular, pruebas-unitarias, karma-jasmine

Soy muy nuevo en esto del unit testing en general. He estado haciendo algunos tests para mi proyecto y hasta ahora todos han funcionado de forma correcta, pero hace un par de días me encontré con un error.
Tengo la sensación de que el error esta en la forma en la que llamo las funciones fixture.detectChanges() y await fixture.whenStable(), pero ya intenté muchos acomodos diferentes y el que muestro en el código es el único que muestra un error con sentido (el resto eran sobre la inexistencia de la función map o regresaba 'undefined' el spy de mi función get).

El comportamiento anormal que veo es que en la función map() dentro del subscribe del método get, el test jamás llega al return, se detiene en el if statement (dejé comentarios en el código señalando esa parte).

Está es la función que quiero probar.

```
subscribeToSearchbar() {
    this.searchbar.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(750)
        )
        .subscribe((value) => {
            if (value == "" || value == null) {
                this.state = 'home'
                return
            }
            this.searchArticlesByQuery(value)
        })
}

searchArticlesByQuery(value) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.apiService.get(`loro/articles/search/${value}`, false, { type: "query" })
        .pipe(
            finalize(()=>{
                this.isLoading = false
                this.state = 'results'
            })
        )
        .subscribe(({ data }) => {
            this.foundArticles = data.map((article) => {
                if (article.keywords){
                    article.keywords = article.keywords.split(',') // el code coverage me muestra que el teste SI cubre esta línea de código
                }
                return article // pero jamás llega a esta, ya que la señala en color rojo
            })
        })
}
```

Y el código de mi test es este:

```
beforeEach(()=>{
    let articles = [
        {id: 1, keywords:'these,are,some,key,words', title: 'First title'},
        {id: 2, keywords:'these,some,key,words', title: 'Second title'}
    ];
    spyOn((component as any).apiService, 'get').and.returnValue(of({data:articles}));
    fixture.detectChanges();
})
it('Should subscribe to search bar with non-empty value in query', async ()=>{
    const subscribeToSearchbar = spyOn(component, 'subscribeToSearchbar').and.callThrough()
    const searchArticlesByQuery = spyOn(component, 'searchArticlesByQuery').and.callThrough()
    const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input')
    el.value = 'these'
    el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
    fixture.detectChanges()
    component.subscribeToSearchbar()
    await fixture.whenStable()
    expect(subscribeToSearchbar).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(searchArticlesByQuery).toHaveBeenCalledWith(el.value)
    expect(component.foundArticles.length).toEqual(2)
})
```

El error que me arroja en consola es este:

```
Chrome Headless 90.0.4430.212 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 26 of 213 SUCCESS (0 secs / 1.562 secs)
12 05 2021 21:16:11.046:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js
12 05 2021 21:16:11.046:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching /_karma_webpack_/polyfills.js
Chrome Headless 90.0.4430.212 (Mac OS 10.15.7) KnowledgeBaseComponent Fetch methods Should subscribe to search bar with non-empty value in query FAILED
    Error: Expected 0 to equal 2.
        at <Jasmine>
        at src/app/layouts/knowledge-knowledge-base.component.spec.ts:66:43
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at fulfilled (node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:73:42)
Chrome Headless 90.0.4430.212 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 30 of 213 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 2.618 secs)
Chrome Headless 90.0.4430.212 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 30 of 213 (1 FAILED) (skipped 183) (3.801 secs / 2.618 secs)
Chrome Headless 90.0.4430.212 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 30 of 213 (1 FAILED) (skipped 183) (3.801 secs / 2.618 secs)
```

Comment: Hola, podrías logear qué estas recibiendo en la variable `data`? en la suscripción dentro del método `searchArticlesByQuery()`. Gracias

Comment: Ya pude resolver, en un momento adjunto la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente, me alegro mucho!